# Avertissement window after actionButton click on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently making a shiny application and I have a feature that allows me to delete or add a row from an array using an "actionButton" as well as the same row in the original array file. However I wanted to know if there was a way to make a warning appear asking the user if he was sure he wanted to delete this row (in shiny or html or JS) before the action is performed of course.

Here is an exemple for adding a line :

```
#ui.R

BDD <- box(title = "Ajout d'un genre ou d'une famille dans la BDD",status = "primary",solidHeader=TRUE, width = 12,                   
            fluidRow(
              # column(12,fileInput(inputId="BDDtxt", label = "Selectionner le Fichier BDD des flore connues")),
              column(4,textInput("Genus_Species", "Genre ou Espèce", value = "")),
              column(5,offset = 2, textInput("description","Note sur la bacterie",value = "")),
              column(12,checkboxGroupInput("flores","Marqueurs de ces flores :",c("Digestive","Cutanée","Oro-pharyngée","environementales"))),
              column(4,offset=2,actionButton("ajouter", "Ajouter à la BDD")),
              column(4,offset=1,actionButton("modifier", "Modifier la BDD"))
              
            )
)
TabBDD <- box(title = "Affichage du tableau  BDD",status = "primary",solidHeader=TRUE, width = 12,                   
              fluidRow(
                column(12,DT::dataTableOutput("TabBDD")),
                column(12,offset=4,actionButton("selectionner","Sélectionner"))
              )
          )

#server.R

      values <- reactiveValues(
        TabBDD = NULL
      )
      
      observe({
        if(file.exists("BDDflore.txt")) {
          values$TabBDD <- read.delim("BDDflore.txt")
        } else {
          NULL
        }
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$ajouter,{
        Tab <- data.frame(
                  Species = input$Genus_Species,
                  Flore = paste(input$flores, collapse = ","),
                  Comment = input$description
        )
        write_delim(Tab,
                    file = "BDDflore.txt",
                    delim = "\t",
                    append = TRUE)
        if (is.null(values$TabBDD)) {
          values$TabBDD <- Tab
        } else {
          values$TabBDD <- rbind(
            values$TabBDD,
            Tab
          )
        }
      })

      output$TabBDD <- DT::renderDataTable({
        if(!is.null(values$TabBDD)){
          values$TabBDD
        }
      })


#BDDflore.txt  

Species Flora   Comment
Propionibacterium acnes Cutanée Marqueur de la flore cutanée
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps with the **shinyalert** package, something like that:

```
observeEvent(input$delete, {
  shinyalert(
    title = "Are you sure?",
    text = "Delete row?", 
    showCancelButton = TRUE,
    cancelButtonText = "No",
    callbackR = function(ok) { 
      if(ok){
        # R code to delete the row
      }
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks !! I just add "useShinyalert()" on the ui.R and that perfect !!